# Raster turns into 4 separate rasters after clipping

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, clip, multi-band

I have a raster with a .sid extension.  After I clip my raster, it produces 4 separate new rasters (3 of which are black and white).  When I delete any of the Black and White rasters, the clipped raster that's in color no longer works.  Is there a way to get around this, or at least combine them all together into a single raster?

I have tried the Composite Bands tool, and that comes up with an error.

Answer (score 3):

Well I figured it out! Hopefully this will help someone else!

Add your Raster and Polygon to clip to.

Open the Image Analysis Toolbar (Go to > Windows > Image Analysis)

Select your Raster in Image Analysis then Select your polygon to clip to.

Select the Clip Icon.

Then Right click on your new raster in the Table of Contents and Export Data.  I used TIFF for my format.  Then I just selected where I wanted to save.  I also hit "Yes" for the popup after I hit save.  Hope this helps

See example 2:
http://gisgeography.com/clip-rasters-arcgis-polygon-boundary/